# Bash Shell cut line from file and insert to another files position using sed

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell

I have one problem and try to solve it by `sed` command.

I have `file.txt` with text in the first line. The text for example is: `# username:blablabla,password:blablabla`, and I have another file named `file.json` with this content:

```
{
  "Subject": {
    "Data": "GitCommit login information",
    "Charset": "UTF-8"
  },
  "Body": {
    "Text": {
      "Data": "This is the message body in text format.",
      "Charset": "UTF-8"
    },
    "Html": {
      "Data": "bad data"
    }
  }
}
```

Question is: How can i replace Json's value is "bad data" with the line from `file.txt`? 
Result must be :

```
{
  "Subject": {
    "Data": "GitCommit login information",
    "Charset": "UTF-8"
  },
  "Body": {
    "Text": {
      "Data": "This is the message body in text format.",
      "Charset": "UTF-8"
    },
    "Html": {
      "Data": "username:blablabla,password:blablabla"
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do with bash command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me preface this answer by saying you should *really* use a JSON parser to properly and safely change your JSON.

That being said, you can do it with `sed` like this:

```
# double backslashes (\); escape special sed-replacement chars (&/\); escape quotes (")
escape_json_for_sed() {
    sed 's/\\/\\&/g; s/[&/\]/\\&/g; s/"/\\\\&/g'
}

sed 's/"Data": "bad data"/"Data": "'"$(head -1 file.txt | escape_json_for_sed)"'"/g' -i file.json
```

Note the helper shell function `escape_json_for_sed()` used on the replacement value read from file. With it, we:

1. escape the characters with special meaning in `sed` replacement string (`/`, `\` and `&`); and
2. escape the quote characters (`"`) which would otherwise terminate the JSON String value, as well as escape the JSON escape char (`\`).

Comment: Thanks for helping ! but then i try to call yours function i get an error , look this :
sed: -e expression #1, char 75: unknown option to `s'
i have script whom generate username and password and put to file.txt first line , this line doesn't have any quotes , i just need to put this line in to Json file in this quotes instead bad data

Comment: The problem could be if your replacement string contains ``/``, ``\``, or ``&``. Those characters must be escaped with ``\``.

Comment: i need to replace json bad data this string : UserName:roberto.viquez,cloneUrlHttp:https://git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/ and etc.
it contain the chars / ,  maybe there is another way to solve this problem ? i just need this text put to string and replace bad data. if i do it my script should be work :(

Comment: I updated the solution to handle special chars in the replacement string.

Comment: OMG !! It works!!!!! Thank you, you are best!! but you need to update answer again , because in beginning should be sed -i .... not only sed:) 
and i have one more question if i generate another user and rather to replace it again , how can i return "bad data"  value then my script complete all lines?

Comment: I've updated the answer again, to handle quotes and escapes inside JSON string. If you wish to apply this to more than one field, you can call them ``user-data-1``, ``user-data-2``, etc, instead of ``bad data``.

Comment: randomir , you help me so much! thanks! my script can be running "n" times , you whrite a sed command to change bad data to my file contain , but if i run it again , it do nothing , because in first time sed command found a "bad data" string in json and replaced it , maybe exist a code , whom after complete all line return default "bad data" in json ? or something else instead ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what are you trying to do. Run the script second time, on the modified json file, and fill in the ``Data`` field with new values? Why can't you just run the script on the template file you had initially?

Comment: yes , i have for example 20 new users , my script create username and password to each of them and save username and password in file.txt. Then i need to put this string from file.txt to data value in file.json to send a email to this user. If i do it one time all ok because bad data changing with your code , but if i create next user in file.json string "bad data" disappear , because this string replaced then i run my script first time. Maybe you know how can i do it right ? i don't know how to create json templates.

Comment: Your initial ``file.json`` is a *template* - you don't have to modify it in place, but instead use it to generate a new ``output.json`` each time: ``sed 's/....' file.json > output-user-x.json``. Or, better yet, use a proper language (like Python) to modify your JSON files.